# namespace and require_once amazonpay

Tags: namespaces, require-once, amazon-pay

i am trying to use amazonpay and encounter the following problem;

when i  `if ($whatever) require_once("amazonpay_stuff.php")` with content:

```
namespace AmazonPay
require_once "apay/config.php";
include 'apay/amazon-pay.phar';
```

and then in the same file where i have the require i try to use

```
$client = new Client($amazonpay_config);
```

this does not work and i get error message

```
Fatal error: Class 'Client' not found in ....
```

when i have all that code in one file;

```
namespace AmazonPay
require_once "apay/config.php";
include 'apay/amazon-pay.phar';
$client = new Client($amazonpay_config);
```

it works fine - how can i make it work with require_once?

Comment: Hi @Janus, I guess you have to watch your namespace handling. Have you tried just using $client = new \AmazonPay\Client($amazonpay_config); everywhere?

Comment: hi @marcus.kreusch thank you for your help, but that did not work :-/ still the "Fatal error: Class 'Client' not found in /www/htdocs/...." error - i tried it with \AmazonPay\Client ... and AmazonPay\Client